# Need help ensuring SQLite3 reads complete in my Node.js function

Tags: sqlite

I have an asynchronous function on JS, which should be performed strictly in parallel, one of the stages is to read the data from the database and their processing, but, SQLite3 is launched asynchronously, I have a function output (the wrong one, because I did not take data from the database) And then data from the database. Can I somehow remain a function and force me to wait for reading, or is it not possible?

I tried to use 'await' waits, remove data through a promise, but unfortunately did not lead to anything

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.